# Iterative formula in Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is it possible to perform an iterative/recursive calculation using Pandas and Numpy? That is, consuming data from a DataFrame and applying the formula efficiently using Numpy functions, instead of doing the calculation step-by-step in using a Python for loop.

For example, how would the Fibonacci sequence look?

[image: Iterative Fibonacci]

Comment: In my opinion need `numba`, check [this](http://stuartmumford.uk/blog/the-fibonacci-sequence.html)

Comment: cumsum and related ufunc accumulate methods shove this kind of iteration into compiled code.  But there isn't a general purpose approach in numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Any constant-coefficient linear recurrence has a closed form solution (there are [many methods of finding them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)). Specifically, for yours, it is [given by the following one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(10))
>>> np.array(((1 + np.sqrt(5))**x - (1 - np.sqrt(5))**x) / (2**x * np.sqrt(5)), dtype=int)
array([ 0,  1,  1,  2,  3,  5,  8, 13, 21, 34])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Fibonacci as an example of an iterative formula. Really I'm working on a backtesting simulation where the inputs to step n are the outputs from step n-1.

Comment: What is the family, though? If it's constant-coefficient linear recurrences, it's solvable easily. Perhaps if you can describe the family, an efficient way will emerge.

Comment: 1 - look at the state of an order book; 2 - decide whether we want to buy or sell; 3 - keep track of balances and profit. My decision to buy or sell at step n can depend on how much profit I've made from steps 1 to n-1. And definitely my profit at step n depends on the profit at step n-1 and the trade I make at step n.

Comment: Personally, I'd use Cython (esp. if you're comfortable with C++). If you're interested, I could write something later.